# How can I port an Eclipse C++ project to Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, project

I have a very complicated project created in Eclipse as a Perforce project, converted to a C++ project.  Is there a way to port the project to one or more Visual Studio 2013 Express projects?

Comment: Found this question when working on a similar problem. Looks like the best(?) solution is to use a neutral build system that is compatible with either IDE.

In the present, it looks like CMake is the most likely candidate. Good long term bet as CMake has good history and uptake. CMake has "generators" to create IDE-specific project files. Takes a while to grok...

Answer (score 1):

I found that I can drag a sub-directory from Windows Explorer directly into a MSVS filter.  Using that method, only `.c`, `.cpp`, `.h`, and `.hpp` files wind up in the filter. It is a big time saver over:

Right-click > Add > Existing Item (or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>), and then navigating and picking only the source and include files, one directory at a time.

**Disclaimer: This is really not a satisfactory solution because there are so many nested sub-directories and the need  to update as files are modified.**

Comment: @Rafael. Glad someone looked at this after all this time, although that problem is way in the past (for me) now. Your edits make the answer clearer, especially moving the disclaimer to the bottom (and calling it that). Thanks. How did you put the Alt-Shift-A in a box? Nice touch, btw.

Comment: Thanks! I used `kbd` html tag

Answer (score 0):

If it is complicated in the sense it just have many source files but it produces a single executable then you could use the Visual Studio option to create a project from existing code. Go to 'File', 'New', 'Project from existing code' and follow the wizard. That should help if all source code is under relatively self-contained directories.
From there, you would need to set the rest manually.
If it is a complicated build process that generated many binaries then you would be out of luck.
Notice that if you can build from the command line then visual studio can act as an editor only.

Comment: The project has the source code spread out over a zillion nested subdirectories (more than a hundred).  Also, I should have said project<U>s</U>, i.e. there will be many projects in the solution folder.  If it was a one time thing, I could just grind through it, but the Perforce project will be updated.  Apparently I cannot install the Perforce plugin on an Express version of MSVS or I would do that instead of going through Eclipse to import the Perforce project and converting to a C++ project.